# Does blocking the Windows App Store via AD group policy also prevent maual appl. installations?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-store

Asuming an organization uses group policies to prevent users from accessing/using the Windows (8/8.1/10) App Store. Does this influence manual program installations (via .msi or exe installers) in any way?
Will users still be able to manually run installers?

Comment: "Does this influence manual program installations (via .msi or exe installers) in any way?" - Windows Store applications cannot be installed this way, so a domain policy surrounding Windows Store applications, only effects Windows Store applications not desktop applications.  "Will users still be able to manually run installers?" - This entirely depends on how the domain is configured there is a domain policy to not allow this also.

Answer (score 1):

No, blocking the windows store will not interfere with normal installations.

Yes, users will still be able to manually run installers, given they have sufficient rights on their computer (eg. they're local admin if an installer requires such).